# ¿Cómo limpiar un elemento de un JSON en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, java

hola necesito limpiar un json pero no he encontrado una  manera de hacerlo con javaScript

```
Json con datos... es demasiado largo para hacerlo manual


  {
"comando": "CalcularViabilidadDelDerecho",
"asesoriaVejez": {
    "afiliado": {
        "genero": "MASCULINO",
        "estadoCivil": "SOLTERO",
        "fechaExpedicionDocumento": "1979-07-11T05:00:00Z",
        "historiaLaboral": {
            "cotizaciones": [{
                    "periodo": {
                        "ano": "1998",
                        "mes": "3"
                    },
                    "aportante": {
                        "id": {
                            "tipo": "NIT",
                            "numero": "892200839"
                        },
                        "nombre": "ALCALDIA MUNICIPAL DE SANTIAGO "
                    },
                    "ibc": 34000,
                    "dias": 3,
                    "fechaPago": "2006-07-04T05:00:00Z",
                    "nombreAFP": "PROTECCION",
                    "extemporanea": null,
                    "valorCotizacionObligatoria": null
                },
```

Json como deseo que quede sin datos

```
  {
"comando": "CalcularViabilidadDelDerecho",
"asesoriaVejez": {
    "afiliado": {
        "genero": "{{sexo}}",
        "estadoCivil": "{{estadocas}}",
        "fechaExpedicionDocumento": "{{fechadoc}}",
        "historiaLaboral": {
            "cotizaciones": [{
                    "periodo": {
                        "ano": "{{anoper}}",
                        "mes": "3"
                    },
                    "aportante": {
                        "id": {
                            "tipo": "{{tipodc}}",
                            "numero": "{{numid}}"
                        },
                        "nombre": "{{razonsocial}} "
                    },
                    "ibc": {{ibc}},
                    "dias": {{dias}},
                    "fechaPago": "{{fechapgo}}",
                    "nombreAFP": "{{nombreaffpp}}",
                    "extemporanea": null,
                    "valorCotizacionObligatoria": null
                },
```

Answer (score 1):

Según lo que se logra comprender, lo que realmente deseas es limpiar ciertas propiedades de tu objeto JSON, por lo que simplemente deberías setear dichas propiedades con llaves vacías de la siguiente manera

```
{
   "comando": "CalcularViabilidadDelDerecho",
   "asesoriaVejez": {
      "afiliado": {
         "genero": null,
         "estadoCivil": null
      }
   }
}
```

Y así sucesivamente. Ahora realmente veo un poco tedioso hacerlo por cada propiedad por lo que te recomiendo setear en null el objeto padre de esta forma

```
{
   "comando": "CalcularViabilidadDelDerecho",
   "asesoriaVejez": {
      "afiliado": {}
   }
}
```

Y a partir del padre ir agregando las propiedades que necesitas, pero obviamente dependerá de lo que estés realizando, eso lo dejo a tu criterio.

Nos comentas si te sirve, saludos!